# How to Check for Deleted Words Between 2 Sentences in Java

Tags: java, string, compare

What's the best approach in Java if you want to check for words that were deleted from sentence A in sentence B. For example:

> Sentence A: I want to delete unnecessary words on this simple sentence.
>
> Sentence B: I want to delete words on this sentence.
>
> Output: I want to delete (unnecessary) words on this (simple) sentence.

where the words inside the  parenthesis are the ones that were deleted from sentence A.

Comment: What techniques have you considered?

Comment: Have you considered [recursion](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bu0X20xOxIs)?

Comment: I havent officially started coding yet. I wanted to gather some ideas first as to how to best implement this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming order doesn't matter: use commons-collections.

1. Use `String.split()` to split both sentences into arrays of words.
2. Use commons-collections' `CollectionUtils.addAll` to add each array into an empty `Set`.
3. Use commons-collections' `CollectionUtils.subtract` method to get A-B.

Comment: Coolness. Will try to work on this one. Thanks for the logic!

Comment: Sets would not work if you have the following String a: "Apple Banana Apple" String b: "Apple".

Comment: Israel didn't mention anything about the cardinality of words. He asked to get all words in A that were not contained in by B. @IsraelSato, if cardinality matters, use a List implementation (such as LinkedLinks) instead of a Set.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming order and position matters, this looks like it would be a variation of the Longest Common Subsequence problem, a dynamic programming solution.

wikipedia has a great page on the topic, there's really too much for me to outline here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else is using really heavy-weight algorithms for what is actually a very simple problem. It could be solved using longest common subsequence, but it's a very constrained version of that. It's not a full diff; it only includes deletes. No need for dynamic programming or anything like that. Here's a 20-line implementation:

```
private static String deletedWords(String s1, String s2) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String[] words1 = s1.split("\\s+");
    String[] words2 = s2.split("\\s+");
    int i1, i2;
    i1 = i2 = 0;
    while (i1 < words1.length) {
        if (words1[i1].equals(words2[i2])) {
            sb.append(words1[i1]);
            i2++;
        } else {
            sb.append("(" + words1[i1] + ")");
        }
        if (i1 < words1.length - 1) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        i1++;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

When the inputs are the ones in the question, the output matches exactly.

Granted, I understand that for some inputs there are multiple solutions. For example:

```
a b a
a
```

could be either `a (b) (a)` or `(a) (b) a` and maybe for some versions of this problem, one of these solutions is more likely to be the "actual" solution than the other, and for those you need some recursive or dynamic programming approach... but let's not make it too much more complicated than what Israel Sato originally asked for!

Comment: Thank you very much for this piece of work, sir! If I understood this correctly, it would check for the words based on its position on the two strings, ie the first word on the sentence A is only compared to the first word on sentence B. If they're not equal, then it's assumed that it's deleted. Am i right?

Comment: Not exactly. Note that i1 is incremented after each loop, but i2 is only incremented sometimes. So for each word that is deleted, i2 lags behind by one more. So index 0 is compared with 0, 1 with 1... until a mismatch ocurrs, at which point i1 is incremented but not i2. From then on, 3 is compared with 2, 4 with 3, etc. And then if another deletion is found, then it would be 6 compared with 4, 7 with 5... and so on.

Comment: Oh okay, yeah, Im seeing it now. But there seems to be a problem when the length of the string in sentence A is bigger than sentence B. For example:

**sentence A** - This is a normal sentence that needs simplification.
**sentence B** - This is a sentence.

**Output:** Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 1):

```
String a = "I want to delete unnecessary words on this simple sentence.";
String b = "I want to delete words on this sentence.";

String[] aWords = a.split(" ");
String[] bWords = b.split(" ");
List<String> missingWords = new ArrayList<String> ();

int x = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < aWords.length; i++) {
  String aWord = aWords[i];
  if(x < bWords.length) {
    String bWord = bWords[x];
    if(aWord.equals(bWord)) {
        x++;
    } else {
        missingWords.add(aWord);
    }
   } else {
      missingWords.add(aWord);
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice job. Thank you very much. Will try to work on this one as well.

Answer (score 0):

This works well....for updated strings also
updated strings enclosed with square brackets.

```
import java.util.*;
class Sample{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);  

    String str1 = sc.nextLine();
    String str2 = sc.nextLine();
    List<String> flist = Arrays.asList(str1.split("\\s+"));
    List<String> slist = Arrays.asList(str2.split("\\s+"));
    List<String> completedString = new ArrayList<String>();
    String result="";
    String updatedString = "";
    String deletedString = "";
    int i=0;
    int startIndex=0;
    int endIndex=0;
    for(String word: slist){
        if(flist.contains(word)){
            endIndex = flist.indexOf(word);
            if(!completedString.contains(word)){
                if(deletedString.isEmpty()){
                    for(int j=startIndex;j<endIndex;j++){
                        deletedString+= flist.get(j)+" ";
                    }
                }
            }
            startIndex=endIndex+1;
            if(!deletedString.isEmpty()){
                result += "("+deletedString.substring(0,deletedString.length()-1)+") ";
                deletedString="";
            }
            if(!updatedString.isEmpty()){
                result += "["+updatedString.substring(0,updatedString.length()-1)+"] ";
                updatedString="";
            }
            result += word+" ";
            completedString.add(word);
            if(i==slist.size()-1){
                endIndex = flist.size();
                for(int j=startIndex;j<endIndex;j++){
                    deletedString+= flist.get(j)+" ";
                }
                startIndex = endIndex+1;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(i == 0){
                boolean boundaryCheck = false;
                for(int j=i+1;j<slist.size();j++){
                    if(flist.contains(slist.get(j))){
                        endIndex=flist.indexOf(slist.get(j));
                        boundaryCheck=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!boundaryCheck){
                    endIndex = flist.size();
                }
                if(!completedString.contains(word)){
                    for(int j=startIndex;j<endIndex;j++){
                        deletedString+= flist.get(j)+" ";
                    }
                }
                startIndex = endIndex+1;
            }else if(i == slist.size()-1){
                endIndex = flist.size();
                if(!completedString.contains(word)){
                    for(int j=startIndex;j<endIndex;j++){
                        deletedString+= flist.get(j)+" ";
                    }
                }
                startIndex = endIndex+1;
            }               
            updatedString += word+" ";
            completedString.add(word);
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(!deletedString.isEmpty()){
        result += "("+deletedString.substring(0,deletedString.length()-1)+") ";
    }
    if(!updatedString.isEmpty()){
        result += "["+updatedString.substring(0,updatedString.length()-1)+"] ";
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

This is basically a differ, take a look at this:

- [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)

and the root algorithm:

- [Longest common subsequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

Here's a sample Java implementation:

- http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/96optimization/Diff.java.html

which compares lines. The only thing you need to do is split by word instead of by line or alternatively put each word of both sentences in a separate line.

If e.g. on Linux, you can actually see the results of the latter option using `diff` program itself before you even write any code, try this:

```
$ echo "I want to delete unnecessary words on this simple sentence."|tr " " "\n" > 1
$ echo "I want to delete words on this sentence."|tr " " "\n" > 2
$ diff -uN 1 2
--- 1   2012-10-01 19:40:51.998853057 -0400
+++ 2   2012-10-01 19:40:51.998853057 -0400
@@ -2,9 +2,7 @@
 want
 to
 delete
-unnecessary
 words
 on
 this
-simple
 sentence.
```

The lines with `-` in front are different (alternatively, it would show `+` if the lines were added into sentence B that were not in sentence A). Try it out to see if that fits your problem.

Hope this helps.