# Colour a Specify letter and word

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using poi api for my development.Let me explain my process.

1.Compare two sentences.
Example :

A1 : **Arun** is well.

A2 : Is **aruni** well.

Here i need to find newly added word in A2 and newly added letter in arun**i** and highlight it with some colours.

How is it possible by using java .?

Thanks..!

Answer (score 1):

This is not specifically java question. It is more of algorithm question. So once you understand algorithm, it will be trivial to implement solution in java in your case.

See this so question: [How to Check for Deleted Words Between 2 Sentences in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682510/how-to-check-for-deleted-words-between-2-sentences-in-java)

and read about [Longest common subsequence"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)